# Complex Survey Site

Tags: php, asp.net, survey

I'm looking to have users register and fill in a complex survey.  There will be multiple branches to the survey, many of them using similar questions from other branches.  There will also be the requirement of uploading multiple files.

My other requirement is that I host this on my own domain.  Preferable PHP, ASP.NET would also be okay.

I was looking at Drupal + Quiz, but I don't think it supports advanced features.

Comment: So are you looking for how to build this form scratch or are you looking for other alternative survey solutions? Where do uploading of files fit into the survey?

Answer (score 0):

I kinda dig LimeSurvey..  I used it a bit - the UI isn't the greatest but it has a lot of features..

http://www.limesurvey.org/

I think it meets all your requirements, though I'm not sure about multiple file uploads.  However, the source is all PHP so you can really do whatever you want.